# Can a subclass be referred to as the type of its super class?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I am making a game at school. I have weapons which is a subclass of items.
And I have a field `currentWeapon` in my class called `BattleGround`. And I have a method to search and iterate through all items in my "backpack". I was hoping to also use this for weapons, since they are also items.

What I was hoping was that an object of the `Weapon` class can be called an item as well. But I just simply do not know. Do I need a new method to iterate through the `Weapon`s? Both `Weapon`s and `Item`s are to be stored in the same backpack.

If I store the field `currentWeapon` as a `Weapon`, I can not use the method and maybe not store `Weapon`s in the `Hashmap` of `String`s and `Item`s. If I store it as an `Item` I can not use the methods of the `Weapon` class. Thank you.

Comment: An example would make it easier to understand I guess.

Comment: Yes, one of the definitions of a subclass is that it is usable wherever an instance of its superclass is needed. So, in your case, if `Weapon extends Item` and there's code that accepts an `Item`, it will also accept a `Weapon`.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it is a fairly easy question though isn´t it?
Can weapons be treated like Items? Can a subclass be treated like the type of the superclass?

Can objects of the subclass weapons be stored in a HashMap<String, Item>?

Comment: @JoakimVindenes Yes to all 3 questions. Look up `Polymorphism`.

Comment: If `Weapon` is a subclass of `Item` this is totally fine.

Comment: Thank you miorel, that was what I wanted to hear.
Now let me show you some code.

In my game my character can type in a choice of weapon. Then it´s going to iterate over all items in backpack to see if it exists, and then store this weapon in the currentWeapon-field (which is of weapon-type).

public Item findItem(String itemName) {
return backpack.get(itemName);
}

But when I try to store what I found in the currentWeapon-field (I'm then now trying to store ITEM in a WEAPON-field, and that´s the wrong way I guess) I get error message "Incompatible types, found Item but expected Weapon".

How?

Comment: @JoakimVindenes If this question got answered then please create a new question if you have additional thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

If `Weapon` is a subclass of `Item`, then you can store a `Weapon` in a collection of `Item` objects without any problems. Perhaps what you need to learn is the `instanceof` operator:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

// add some items to the list

for (Item item : items) {
  if (item instanceof Weapon) {
    Weapon weapon = (Weapon) item; // cast the item to a weapon
    weapon.someWeaponMethod();
  }
}
```

If you use `instanceof`, you can determine whether your `Item` is in fact a `Weapon`.

Comment: On a whole other note: `instanceOf` checks should not be used often though! Sometimes there is a solution available and using `instanceOf` indicates *design smell*.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I don't think you can make a sweeping statement like that. As with any programmatic idiom, you really have to see the context to understand whether it's the "correct" choice.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that you are casting the item to a weapon there. This allows us to access methods and fields defined in `Weapon` instead of just the `Item` ones.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Good point - I've made the code example clearer.

Comment: @NarendraPathai You are right, this looks like a design smell, but the problem is somewhere else. I think the weapons should not be stored along with all other items, but in such a case I think using `instanceof` is cleaner that e.g. introduce some `itemType` property or whatever.

Comment: True, but I am not saying that your solution is incorrect. It is just to take into attention that this should not be happening.